# how assign vector in below program?

Tags: c++

can anyone tell me what this line is doing in below program`res.back().insert(end(res.back()), begin(ity->second), end(ity->second));` ,How 
I want to assign elements to res using loops not above statement but it will be 
good for me if you explain how above statement is assigning the elements and 
how can i do same using loops.

Task :  https://leetcode.com/problems/vertical-order-traversal-of-a-binary-tree/

code : https://ideone.com/E40syr

```
vector<vector<int>> verticalTraversal(TreeNode* r, vector<vector<int>> res = {}) {
    map<int, map<int, set<int>>> m;
    dfs(r, 0, 0, m);
    for (auto itx = m.begin(); itx != m.end(); ++itx) {
        res.push_back(vector<int>());
        for (auto ity = itx->second.begin(); ity != itx->second.end(); ++ity) {
            res.back().insert(end(res.back()), begin(ity->second), end(ity->second));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `res.back()` is a `vector<int>`. Did you read some documentation for `std::vector::insert`?

Comment: Try to [explain it to a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Needless to try to answer you question without the needed information:
Definition of `dfs`
Definition of TreeNode
Intention

Comment: @Superlokkus i am one of the biggest fans of a mcve myself, but neither `TreeNode` nor `dfs` are needed to answer the question, actually they are irrelevant and could be removed from the mcve

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I see your point.

Comment: @Superlokkus Now please help sir

Comment: please clarify: What is unclear about the code? Why do you want to replace the algorithm with a loop?

Comment: @aka123 She/he was right about that dfs or tree node might be irrelevant, but your context and intention and clear problem statement i.e. question still needs improvement.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 please see edited one

Comment: you merely added links (that I didnt open because what is important to the quesiton should be in the question not hidden behind links) but it is still not clear what part of the answer you didnt get when reading some documentation for `std::vector::insert`

Answer (score 1):

```
res.back()
```

Gets the last element in `res`.

```
.insert(end(res.back()),
```

Insert something at this position.

```
begin(ity->second), end(ity->second)
```

The iterator range to be inserted.

```
);
```

You could assign this is a loop by

```
for (auto itz : ity->second)
  res.back().push_back(itz);
```

Comment: please explain properly

Comment: There are many function calls in this line. Can you let us know which parts you understand and which parts are troubling? Btw welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: Also, end(res.back()) : this [std::end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/) gives end iterator of res.back() . Similar (maybe exactly same in case of vector, advise please) to what you would get using res.back().end() .

Comment: True. Because the insert position is at the end you could use a loop with `push_back`.